# Removing child entity when editing parent entity in embedded form if field is null - Symfony 4

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I am using symfony 4 and I have two entities; a Product and a ProductImage. I have created a OneToOne relationship between the two and I have embedded the ProductImageType form inside my ProductType form, since one product has one image. The field that I have embedded in the ProductType form is 'url' which belongs to the ProductType entity.

This all works as expected when creating a new product if I leave the image url blank then a record is not created in the ProductImage table. And if I provide a url then a record is created. However, if I edit a product which has a image url and remove the image url then I get an error. What I was hoping for is that the related ProductImage entity would just be set to null on it's url field or better yet, the related child ProductImage would just be removed from the database completely. The error I receive is:

`Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "url".`

I don't understand how this is happening since the url field of the ProductImage is allowed to be null. What is the best way of going about fixing this? Any help greatly appreciated!

Product Code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProductImage", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $image;

public function getImage(): ?ProductImage
{
    return $this->image;
}

public function setImage(ProductImage $image): self
{
    $this->image = $image;

    if ($this !== $image->getProduct()) {
        $image->setProduct($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

ProductImage ccode:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $url;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="image", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\Type(type="App\Entity\Product")
 */
private $product;

public function getProduct(): ?Product
{
    return $this->product;
}

public function setProduct(Product $product): self
{
    $this->product = $product;

    return $this;
}
```

ProductImageType code:

```
->add('url', TextType::class, [
    'label' => 'Image Url',
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'A url to the image of this Product.'
        ]
    ]);
```

ProductType code:

```
->add('image', ProductImageType::class, [
    'required' => false,
])
```

Comment: Maybe a cache problem, clear it and try again - because you're right with ?string it should not throw this error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just cleared all my cache and migrated the a fresh database again, but still the same issue unfortunately. *Edit* Actually I just noticed that set url method should not have been included in my question as it is for a separate url property in the Product entity. @rebru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetUrl in ProductImage entity was missing a '?' before 'string'.

```
public function setUrl(?string $url): self
{
    $this->url = $url;

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe orphanRemoval on ProductImage->$product?;

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="...", orphanRemoval=true)
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* @Assert\Type(type="App\Entity\Product")
*/
```

`private $product;`